# Javascript Form Validation referencing issue

Tags: javascript, forms, validation

Im trying to validate a form for an assignment and have hit a wall, apologies in advance if I miss the obvious Im quite new to programming.

Im trying to validate multiple form fields to check for erroneous data before the form is submitted. I have a separate function in an external file for each type of field that holds a regex and checks the input and acts on the result.

My problem is that I built the functions to need parameters to work.
At the moment I have the functions placed in the onblur section of each field to validate and provide feedback as the user progresses through the form. Now when I want to build a master function to call all the functions in the onsubmit section of the form my referencing wont work, I must be missing something trivial but I've gone over the code again and again.

Sample onblur code:

```
<tr><td>Any number</td>
<td><input type="text" id="anyNumber" name="anyNumber" size="10" maxlength="4" 
onblur="validateNumber('anyNumberP', 'anyNumber', anyNumber.value);"/>
</td>
<td>
<p style="display:inline;" id='anyNumberP'> </p>
```

Sample External File Function:

```
function validateNumber(pId, id, value){
    var inputCorrectMsg = "<--Input is Valid";
    var inputIncorrectMsg = "<--Error: Please enter a number.";
    var regEx = /\d\d\d\d/;
    var trimValue = value.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/, '');
    var trimValue1 = trimValue.replace(/^0+/g, '');
    var result = regEx.test(trimValue1);
    if (result == true){
    feedbackColour(pId, id, result, inputCorrectMsg);
    } else{
        feedbackColour(pId, id, result, inputIncorrectMsg);
        }
        return result;
}
```

What I need to be able to do from the external file:

```
function lastCheck(){
var result1 = validateNumber('anyNumberP', 'anyNumber', anyNumber.value);
var result2 = validateOtherStuff('etc', 'etc', 'etc');
if(result1 && result2 = false){
return false;
    }else{
    return true;
    }
}
```

I tried the referencing the function like above but it wont work in my master function. Wether its the reference to the function or the variables passed to the function im not sure. If anyone can help id REALLY appreciate it, thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure if this is the only problem, but this is defintly not right: `if(result1 && result2 = false)` This will ALWAYS be false. You are setting result2 to be false every time you check, and this is equal to writing (result1 && false). You ment to do this: `if(result1 === false && result2 === false)`, and a shorter version is this: `if(!(result1 || result2))`

Comment: May by it is because of order of <script> tags, that include your javascript files? The first should be that where validateNumber defined.
Could you please demonstrate the problem online?

Comment: Hi Aviv, I was rushing the question, usually I declare a variable and set the value to result 1 && result 2 and then test the variable. This isn't the main issue, thanks for the feedback though. @Rodion, the include file is working perfectly as there are functions declared before these that are working perfectly, not sure how I can demo online as it's not live. I need to be able to pass the form field names and values etc. as parameters into a function, that lies inside another function which doesn't take parameters and lies in a correctly included external .js file